# How to create multiple object using single object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

having this type of data

```
 {
     "time_1": 20, 
     "time_2": 10,
     "time_3": 40, 
     "time_4": 30
 }
```

and expected result

```
[
 {
  "key1": "time_1",
  "key2": 20,
 },
 { 
  "key1": "time_2",
  "key2": 10,
 },
 { 
  "key1": "time_3",
  "key2": 40,
 },
 { 
  "key1": "time_4",
  "key2": 30,
 }
]
```

How to convert object to array using JavaScript? I have updated my question.

Comment: Use `Object.entries` and `Array`s `map` method - simples - `const yourExpected Result=Object.entries(yourInputObject).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) methods to iterate over your object and then use the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to transform your object to the array structure you need.

```js
var data = {
  "0": "value1",
  "1": "value2"
}

var newData = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
  [key]: data[key]
}))

console.log(newData)
```

**--Update--**

You would simply need to change the object being returned from the callback function passed to the `.map()` method.

```js
var data =  {
     "time_1": 20, 
     "time_2": 10,
     "time_3": 40, 
     "time_4": 30
 }

var newData = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
  "key1": key,
  "key2": data[key]
}))

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: I have updated my question can you answer that?

Comment: @Sid009, have made an update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

given data

```
const data = {
 "time_1": 20, 
 "time_2": 10,
 "time_3": 40, 
 "time_4": 30
```

}

get all keys of data object

```
const KeysOfData = Object.keys(data);
```

get expected output like this -  [
{
"key1": "time_1",
"key2": 20,
},
]

```
const result = KeysOfData.map(key => {
  const value = data[key]
  return {
    key1: key,
    key2: value
  }
});
```